# Did the French right wing ever call to vote for left wing candidates prior to 2012?

Tags: election, history, france, campaigning

I am searching for any occasions, prior to 2012 and especially between 1995 and 2007, at which the right wing, especially the French President Jacques Chirac himself, called to vote for left wing when the extreme-right wing was against the left wing and the right wing was not there.

My prior research showed no such occasion for presidential elections, nor for regional or legislative elections but I might have missed some occasions.

Comment: DId you have a look at https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_r%C3%A9publicain_(Ve_R%C3%A9publique) ?
Nothing official about Chirac though, but some references may be worth a look.

Comment: @Gwen Yes I checked it out and only found the contrary events: left wing voting for right wing